# How to pass a variable from a Request as the return value of the global function js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, tedious

Hello and thank you in advance. I'm using npm tedious package to interact with a database. I'm also using Meteor.call and methods, for which I need to pass a variable (newdata in the example below) that carries the data taken from the database as the return value of the function "rr", so that I would be able to use the result of the function in the client by a Meteor call.

```
 function rr(){
        var newdata = [];

        var ahora = new Request("SELECT * FROM prueba", function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("err1");
                } else {
                }
            })
            ahora.on('row', function(columns) {
                columns.forEach(function(column) {
                    newdata.push(column.value);
                       });
                });
}
```

I want "newdata" to be the result of the rr function. How can I do that? If I write "return newdata" it's undefined, I can't use await because newdata is not the return value of any function...

Thank you very much.

Comment: which Request package are you using ? As request package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) just gives us response from a url. How come you are executing sql query using Request . ?

Comment: @vinitpayal The `Request` class comes from tedious: http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/

Comment: @Tulir my bad!! Thanks for letting me know wasn't aware about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tedious doesn't seem to support promises natively, but you can wrap your function in a promise:

```
function rr() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var ahora = new Request("SELECT * FROM prueba", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
        var newdata = [];
        ahora.on('row', function(columns) {
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                newdata.push(column.value);
            });
        });
        resolve(newdata);
    }
}
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
function rr() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new Request("SELECT * FROM prueba")
            .on("error", reject)
            .on("row", function(columns) {
                resolve(columns.map(column => column.value))
            });
    }
}
```

If you'd rather not make promises manually, you can try Bluebird's [promisify function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html). I also found  a tedious-specific promisifying package [tedious-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious-promises), but it doesn't seem to be properly maintained.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
function rr(){
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               new Request("SELECT * FROM prueba", (err, rowCount) => {err && reject(err);})
                      .on('row', columns => resolve(columns.map(c => c.value)));
    });
}
```